# How does this simplify? Explanation

Tags: boolean, boolean-logic, boolean-expression

```
AB(CD+D+C)
AB(C+D(1+C)
AB(C+D)
```

I had this as an example and I didn't really understand what laws it used to get to this point. I know that using Nulls Law (OR) that 1+C = 1 so it leaves AB(C+D) but I didn't understand how AB(CD+D+C) becomes AB(C+D(1+C) ? What laws does it use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
If c=1. Then AB(CD+D+1) which is equal to AB.
If c=0 Then AB(0+D+0) which is equal to AB*D.
If d=1 Then AB(CD+1+C) wich is equal to AB.
If d=0 Then AB(0+0+C) which is equal to AB*C.
```

This means that having C or D is enough to have 1 so you can simply take off CD and end with AB(C+D). In every case: AB | A | B is equal to A|B because the latter is a sufficient condition.